# sending a command line using Runtime don't do anything, and no exception even?

Tags: windows, command-line, netsh

I am trying to send `netsh wlan start hostednetwork` to the command prompt, nothing happens, and no messages, no exceptions, and it will not share

Here is my code:

```
String command = "netsh wlan start hostednetwork";
String runas = "runas /noprofile  /user:mymachine\\administrator ";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(runas+command);
```

Note: this command needs administrator privilege.

[image]

Please I can't think about anything to solve it, this is three days I am trying to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass each command line argument as a separate method argument like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[] {"netsh", "wlan", "start", "hostednetwork", "runas", "/noprofile",  "/user:mymachine\\administrator"})
```

Otherwise, it seems like the command name is `netsh wlan start hostednetwork runas /noprofile  /user:mymachine\\administrator`.

Comment: `You must run this command from a command prompt with administrator privilege.` this is the result.

Comment: Then run the java program with administrator privilege.

Comment: Java program? Why java program, the problem is within the command prompt!

Comment: The same error if you type the code into the command prompt? Then this isn't a java problem. Delete the java tag if so.

Comment: _Why the java program_! This is very funny!

Comment: I'm taking off the [tag:java] tag

Comment: Yes, it needs the administrator privilege, but I used `ranas` command to prevent this, I am confused know actually, as they said `ranas` slove this problem.